# Selenium's find_elements_by_class_name is not working and I can't understand why

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I'm very new to web scraping technologies so pardon me if I'm making a silly mistake.

From this website https://onlinebusiness.icbc.com/qmaticwebbooking/#/ I'm trying to set up a notifier that alerts me when a time slot on the calendar is available (you can see the calendar I'm talking about if you select option B under "select a service" and any location under "select a location").

In the picture below is the HTML for the calendar, and you can see the class for a date that is clickable and a date that isn't clickable. The class is "v-btn v-btn--active v-btn--floating v-btn--disabled theme--light" for the greyed out dates which aren't clickable, and the class is "v-btn v-btn--active v-btn--floating theme--light" for dates which are clickable.

[HTML of the calendar dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1W4D.png)

My code to grab the dates with the class name "v-btn v-btn--active v-btn--floating v-btn--disabled theme--light" is below:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://onlinebusiness.icbc.com/qmaticwebbooking/#/')

result = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('v-btn v-btn--active v-btn--floating v-btn--disabled theme--light')
print(result)
```

The code above is simply printing '[ ]' even though there clearly are elements with the class name it is searching for. Looking for help on fixing this issue.

This is my entire program if you want to see it, everything else works so far: [my entire program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Qb0R.png)

Comment: I believe you cannot use class_name with spaces. Try using css_selector. For each className if it is a child add "." in front of the className, if the classes are on the same level, replace the space with ".". First class must also start with a ".". So something like ```result = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.v-btn.v-btn--active.v-btn--floating.v-.btn--disabled.theme--light')```

Comment: You should also give Xpath a try. It will work anyways with accurate and fast result!

Comment: I would use Xpath, but I don't know which dates I'd want to select. It would depend on whether the date has a slot or not.

Comment: @NicLaforge I tried what you said. The issue is the value inside 'return' is only one item long, even though there are many dates with the given class I'm looking for. How would I make it so that 'result' contains all the elements with the provided css.

Also, this is what return is -> [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="471f31d471d5c5c01986600ce682d342", element="861e8fef-8c0e-4686-8c29-a8dbdac7d74d")>]

I'm not sure if that actually points to the element I'm trying to obtain it.

Comment: @crescendo01 Ensure you add only the classes that you need. Only select meaningful classes. Strongly discourage using xPath. It is slower and tend to break on each code change from UI devs. Just checked the website and I don't see v-btn--active on all items. Only the selected one. If you are looking for all dates you can use: '.v-picker button'. If you are looking for only clickable date, try: ```.v-picker button:not(.v-btn--disabled)```. This second will select all buttons that under the data picker that do not have the class "v-btn--disabled"